# Ubuntu 20.04.1 installer crashes

Tags: system-installation, hardware, drive

- Ubuntu Server 20.04.01 installer always crashes right at the moment when the first Subiquity step appears (Choose Language step).
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 installer always crashes after partitioning settings step (at "Where are you?" step with the timezones map). When trying to install onto HDD the crash happens a bit later.

Hardware:

- CPU: Intel Pentium Gold G5420
- Motherboard: ASUS PRIME B365M-A
- SSD: Samsung EVO 500GB
- HDD: some Western Digital
- RAM: 16 GB Hynix (4x4Gb)

Booting from USB flash drive in UEFI mode.

Bootable USB flash drive was created with "Startup Disk Creator" from Ubuntu 18.04.

In BIOS:

- Fast Boot is turned off.
- Secure Boot enabled, Platform Key unloaded, OS type "Other OS".

Memtest86+ 5.01 quickly gets to 31% and then freezes, not sure how to interpret this.

Live Ubuntu tryout works unreliably — either crashes or works fine with no certain triggers to find (felt like SSD-related IO is involved, but no hard evidence).

---

Going to try other versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If Memtest86 is freezing (or otherwise not completing) then you have bad RAM. If this is a custom build/upgrade, make sure the memory modules are properly seated without any gunk on the leads. If Memtest86 continues to fail, try running with just two of the memory sticks to determine which memory module is bad. Hopefully it can be replaced under warranty.